# User Repository With Web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I just started working on web api 2 and trying to get my head in . I created a simple web api 2 project and what i want is to make token based authentication with my own custom User Repository . I want to fetch /update/create/Delete user using my own custom repository .

My repository is in different project and i want to use it here .

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

some where at this point `userManager.FindAsync` . How can i plug my repository into it

Comment: So what is your Question?

Comment: How to can i use my repository . Because all i see is that i need to user UserManager / UserStore

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the built in `UserManager` you could simply replace it with a call to your repository.

```
var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

could be changed to get a user from your repository. Like the following:

```
var userRepository = new UserRepository();

ApplicationUser = await userRepository.GetUserByUserNameAndPasswordAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);`
```

I would probably stick with the `UserManager` and let it do it's things. You can extend the `ApplicationUser` with the properties you need, and you can even create a UserRepository which takes loads its data from the same table as the UserManager.

If you're using Entity Framework you simple expose a `DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }` in your `DbContext` class.